# JSON Response Special Character converted to entity code in html

Tags: jquery, json, fullcalendar

I'm returning a JSON response from the server as

```
{"title":"St. Patrick's Day"}
```

On the front end its being converted to a special character as

```
St Patrick&amp;#039;s Day
```

Does anyone have any idea as to how to convert it back. I'm using full calendar.

Comment: Would you please add a fiddle with your code? Also now that fullcalendar has 2 versions, which one are you using? I tried using the same title and it shows just fine.

Comment: I am using version 1.6.4.

Comment: probably your IDE encoding is messing things up...

Comment: I encoded the json response in php and it works fine but when I did the same using jsp and jstl, this problem crops up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with Full Calendar is that it does not insert the code as html code but as val() so we will have to use the eventRender property and insert the title as a html:

```
eventRender: function(event,element){
  element.find('fc-event title').html(event.title);
}
```

After this code is written, the values get inserted as html elements and not as apecial chars.

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar does not show the code as HTML, example: `<strong>`, `&amp`, etc. So, in this case, you should convert the text using eventRender to remove the tags.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {                                          
    element.find('div.fc-title').html(element.find('div.fc-title').text());                   
}
```

You need to find the correct element tag and replace it. In order to help you, you can use the inspector of [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), for example.

Comment: You should fix the inline HTML that's getting hidden. What does "May you must have to find" mean?